# Java Swing can't add multiple panels to panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm trying to add 2 panels to one panel. Now the problem is, when I add the first or the second one alone, I can see them in the panel.
But when I add both off them (put //add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH); out of comment) I don't see any of them. The Weblabel("Test") is always showing.
Now both panels have a onclick method and when you can't see them (if they are both added) the onclick still works if you click where the panels are supposed to be.

I already tried other layoutmanagers but without succes. Does anyone know where this problem could be comming from?

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(panel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(new WebLabel("Test"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
//add(panel2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

I initialize both panels in my constructor.

```
public MultipleFloorPlanEntityPanel(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate,   FloorPlanEntityPanel panel1, FloorPlanEntityPanel panel2){
    this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
    this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    this.panel1 = panel1;
    this.panel2 = panel2;
    layoutComponents();
}
```

---

**Solved**: reinitialized the extra panels and that worked :)

Comment: Please, show how you initialize **panel1** and **panel2**, I think problem in it

Comment: Welcome to SO, B13ZT! Please do not add (solved) in your title, but instead click the checkmark on the answer you want to accept. This will help future users to find the solution (and search engines can use that info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you need panel contain two panel? try this

```
JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1))
JPanel left = new JPanel();
JPanel right = new JPanel();
top.add(left);
top.add(right);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(top);
frame.setSize(400,400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```